# making a .jar file with source and project structure?

Tags: java, ant, jar

I wonder if this is possible with `ant` and `java`:

I have a Java project which looks like this:

```
./
  build.xml
  src/
    com/
      example/
        {.java files here} 
  bin/
    com/
      example/
        {compiled .class files here} 
  lib/
    {3rd-party jar files here}
  dist/
    {jar file(s) here}
```

I know how to make a .jar file that contains the stuff in the `bin/` directory, with the right manifest to make it run my main Java class.

What I would like to do, if possible, is to make a .jar file that:

1. Java can execute ("java -jar myproject.jar")
2. Someone else can unzip to create the project structure. (including all the subdirectories except for the "dist/" directory)

Is this possible? I can't seem to tell Java to use the bin/ subdirectory of the .jar file as the classpath, I may be screwing up the syntax somehow.

**edit:** Okay, it sounds like trying to make one object serve two (too many) purposes. I have abandoned this approach, instead creating a standard .jar file as the executable, and a .zip file with the source (the build.xml + the src and lib directories). That way there are 2 easy downloads, more than 1 file but not too bad.

Comment: Why would you want to put source files in the jar ? In you want to distribute an executable jar, they won't be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `UrlClassLoader` always tries to find classes based in the root, and a jar URL will always fetch entries based in the root of the jar file.

You *could* create a jar file which has binaries from the root, but source files under src etc. That wouldn't be too bad, assuming you really do just have `com` as the only "root" package.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* put your project on a public SVN server, and just include instructions on how to check out the source - you'd also benefit from other people's check-ins and improvements (hopefully not vandalism).

Comment: I'm doing that anyway, I just want to make it more convenient for users.